# Regex add special characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this regex:

```
var characterReg = /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;
```

How do I include the letters: Å, Ø, Æ, å, ø, æ ?

Comment: In which language? Regex Unicode features are different from engine to engine (Just adding those chars to the character class works pretty much everywhere.)

Comment: In my answer you can try pasting in the characters. But the thread shows other ways.

Comment: Should it be like: /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/\åøæÆÅØ ?

Comment: The square brackets define a character class, there you define which chars are allowed, so `[a-zA-Z0-9,\sÅØÆåøæ]` could be working.

Comment: Works: /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,ø,å,æ,Å,Æ,Ø\s]+\s*$/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the unicode values:

```
\u{1234}{2}
```

for perl, use:

```
\x{1234}{2}
```

will match the 1234 unicode character twice.

There is much more information on this here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

In ruby, looks like unicode support is half-baked:
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/133538

Comment: "In ruby, looks like unicode support is half-baked", yes, in 2007 when that was written it was.